# Should I use web API between my own projects?

Tags: rest, api, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am coding in Visual Studio, and I have a big solution of projects. One of these projects is like a "Repository" project that does all queries to the databases. I also have multiple web apps and web APIs. One of these web APIs is specifically used for a web app that a partner have created. As it turns out now, the partner is gonna quit and is putting me in charge of his web app.

I have plans on working on the web app to make it bigger, but I have a question about what I should do. Should I keep on expanding the web API on my end as well, to serve all needs for the web app, or should I try to integrate the project code into my solution instead, so it can access the repository directly?

Everything is in Azure, in the same region and in the same subscription. I dont know if that changes anything. Is there any best practice about this?

Comment: To answer this question we would need much more information about the projects.

Comment: Im not trying to be specific about my projects. So its common to have both approaches? I feel like its extra work to develop and maintain an API between two projects than to integrate it with the existing repository that the web API would use. Basically, it would be just to move the code in the web API into the new project.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends. If you have two independent projects that only shares the same backend (SQL database), I would recommend to implement two repositories (one in each project) and don't share a common repository between both projects (neither using an API nor using a project reference). A modern (microservice) approach is that each application has its / uses its own datastore with the optimal storage type for each application.